# How to run 2 load cells each with a HX711 on Rpi

Tags: xorg

I've been tinkering, reading watching for weeks and been able only make little progress.
First off I have zero knowledge about Python coding (did some ABAP 18 years ago). I'm trying to help my son to get a home build wind tunnel up and running. We have attached 2 load cells to capture drag and lift of an airfoil. After some primitive thinking and connecting I was able to understand better and the current interfacing looks like this:

- each load cell (one vertical, one horizontal) are connected to their own HX711 modules
- each HX711 module is interfaced with a Raspberry Pi B+ v1.2
- each HX711 module is connected to separate 3.3v pins
- one HX711 is connected to GPIOs 5 and 6; the other 17 and 27
- I use a pre-coded example.py for HX711
- I get error messages when debugging and whenever I place a weight on 1 load cell I get same values displayed (printed) for the other one
- from my little understanding from just looking at the codes is I would not need to modify HX711 which creates a class and thought I load it for each HX711 module with their respective GPIOs ?!

original code

```
>`#! /usr/bin/python2

import time
import sys

EMULATE_HX711=False

referenceUnit = 1

if not EMULATE_HX711:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from hx711 import HX711
else:
    from emulated_hx711 import HX711

def cleanAndExit():
    print("Cleaning...")

    if not EMULATE_HX711:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        
    print("Bye!")
    sys.exit()

hx = HX711(5, 6)

'# I've found out that, for some reason, the order of the bytes is not always the same between versions of python, numpy and the hx711 itself.'
'# Still need to figure out why does it change.'
'# If you're experiencing super random values, change these values to MSB or LSB until to get more stable values.'
'# There is some code below to debug and log the order of the bits and the bytes.'
'# The first parameter is the order in which the bytes are used to build the "long" value.'
'# The second paramter is the order of the bits inside each byte.'
'# According to the HX711 Datasheet, the second parameter is MSB so you shouldn't need to modify it.'
hx.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")

'# HOW TO CALCULATE THE REFFERENCE UNIT'
'# To set the reference unit to 1. Put 1kg on your sensor or anything you have and know exactly how much it weights.'
'# In this case, 92 is 1 gram because, with 1 as a reference unit I got numbers near 0 without any weight'
'# and I got numbers around 184000 when I added 2kg. So, according to the rule of thirds:'
'# If 2000 grams is 184000 then 1000 grams is 184000 / 2000 = 92.'
hx.set_reference_unit(235)


hx.reset()

hx.tare()

print("Tare done! Add weight now...")

'# to use both channels, you'll need to tare them both'
#hx.tare_A()
#hx.tare_B()

while True:
    try:
        # These three lines are usefull to debug wether to use MSB or LSB in the reading formats
        # for the first parameter of "hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")".
        # Comment the two lines "val = hx.get_weight(5)" and "print val" and uncomment these three lines to see what it prints.
        
        # np_arr8_string = hx.get_np_arr8_string()
        # binary_string = hx.get_binary_string()
        # print binary_string + " " + np_arr8_string
        
        # Prints the weight. Comment if you're debbuging the MSB and LSB issue.
        val = max(0, int (hx.get_weight(5)))
        print(val)

        # To get weight from both channels (if you have load cells hooked up 
        # to both channel A and B), do something like this
        #val_A = hx.get_weight_A(5)
        #val_B = hx.get_weight_B(5)
        #print "A: %s  B: %s" % ( val_A, val_B )

        hx.power_down()
        hx.power_up()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanAndExit()
`
```

my version :)

```
>`#! /usr/bin/python2

import time
import sys

EMULATE_HX711=False

referenceUnit = 1

if not EMULATE_HX711:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from hx711 import HX711
else:
    from emulated_hx711 import HX711

def cleanAndExit():
    print("Cleaning...")

    if not EMULATE_HX711:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        
    print("Bye!")
    sys.exit()

hx1 = HX711(5, 6)
hx2 = HX711(27, 17)

'# I've found out that, for some reason, the order of the bytes is not always the same between versions of python, numpy and the hx711 itself.'
'# Still need to figure out why does it change.'
'# If you're experiencing super random values, change these values to MSB or LSB until to get more stable values.'
'# There is some code below to debug and log the order of the bits and the bytes.'
'# The first parameter is the order in which the bytes are used to build the "long" value.'
'# The second paramter is the order of the bits inside each byte.'
'# According to the HX711 Datasheet, the second parameter is MSB so you shouldn't need to modify it.'
hx1.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")
hx2.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")

'# HOW TO CALCULATE THE REFFERENCE UNIT'
'# To set the reference unit to 1. Put 1kg on your sensor or anything you have and know exactly how much it weights.'
'# In this case, 92 is 1 gram because, with 1 as a reference unit I got numbers near 0 without any weight'
'# and I got numbers around 184000 when I added 2kg. So, according to the rule of thirds:'
'# If 2000 grams is 184000 then 1000 grams is 184000 / 2000 = 92.'
hx1.set_reference_unit(200)
hx2.set_reference_unit(6)


hx1.reset()
hx2.reset()

hx1.tare()
hx2.tare()

print("Tare done! Add weight now...")

'# to use both channels, you'll need to tare them both'
#hx.tare_A()
#hx.tare_B()

while True:
    try:
        # These three lines are usefull to debug wether to use MSB or LSB in the reading formats
        # for the first parameter of "hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")".
        # Comment the two lines "val = hx.get_weight(5)" and "print val" and uncomment these three lines to see what it prints.
        
         #np_arr8_string = hx.get_np_arr8_string()
         #binary_string = hx.get_binary_string()
         #print (binary_string + " " + np_arr8_string)
        
        # Prints the weight. Comment if you're debbuging the MSB and LSB issue.
        val_hx1 = max(0, int (hx1.get_weight(5)))
        val_hx2 = max(0, int (hx1.get_weight(27)))
        print ("lift: %s drag: %s" % (val_hx1, val_hx2))

        # To get weight from both channels (if you have load cells hooked up 
        # to both channel A and B), do something like this
        #val_A = hx.get_weight_A(5)
        #val_B = hx.get_weight_B(5)
        #print "A: %s  B: %s" % ( val_A, val_B )

        hx1.power_down()
        hx2.power_down()
        hx1.power_up()
        hx2.power_up()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.cleanup()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanAndExit()
```

This a test and a 1kg weight is placed on one load cell
Tare done! Add weight now...

- lift: 44 drag: 0
- lift: 0 drag: 0
- lift: 0 drag: 0
- lift: 0 drag: 0
- lift: 0 drag: 408
- lift: 1215 drag: 4414
- lift: 4987 drag: 6169
- lift: 6692 drag: 6669
- lift: 6410 drag: 6456
- lift: 6646 drag: 6800
- lift: 6621 drag: 6580
- lift: 6845 drag: 5338

^CCleaning...
Bye!

This is a debug result in Thonny which doesn't say anything to me

> > > %FastDebug example.py
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/home/pi/Downloads/hx711py-master/example.py", line 25, in 
> > > hx1 = HX711(5, 6)
> > > File "/home/pi/Downloads/hx711py-master/hx711.py", line 42, in **init**
> > > self.set_gain(gain)
> > > File "/home/pi/Downloads/hx711py-master/hx711.py", line 64, in set_gain
> > > GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, False)
> > > RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Any tips how I can resolve this would be awesomeness great.
Also can I print results in addition on the screen to a csv file ?

(sorry got long and can't get the formatting right...)

EDIT:
I followed the tutorial from here [Build a digital Raspberry Pi Scale](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/digital-raspberry-pi-scale-weight-sensor-hx711/)

load cell to HX711

- Red: E+
- Black: E-
- Green: A-
- White: A+

HX711 to Rpi

- VCC to Raspberry Pi Pin 1 (3.3V)
- GND to Raspberry Pi Pin 6 (GND)
- DT to Raspberry Pi Pin 29 (GPIO 5)
- SCK to Raspberry Pi Pin 31 (GPIO 6)

I changed only the voltage and adequately I connected the second HX711 to DT to GPIO 27 and SCK to GPIO 17.

HX711.py code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading



class HX711:

    def __init__(self, dout, pd_sck, gain=128):
        self.PD_SCK = pd_sck

        self.DOUT = dout

        # Mutex for reading from the HX711, in case multiple threads in client
        # software try to access get values from the class at the same time.
        self.readLock = threading.Lock()
        
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.PD_SCK, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.DOUT, GPIO.IN)

        self.GAIN = 0

        # The value returned by the hx711 that corresponds to your reference
        # unit AFTER dividing by the SCALE.
        self.REFERENCE_UNIT = 1
        self.REFERENCE_UNIT_B = 1

        self.OFFSET = 1
        self.OFFSET_B = 1
        self.lastVal = int(0)

        self.DEBUG_PRINTING = False

        self.byte_format = 'MSB'
        self.bit_format = 'MSB'

        self.set_gain(gain)

        # Think about whether this is necessary.
        time.sleep(1)

        
    def convertFromTwosComplement24bit(self, inputValue):
        return -(inputValue & 0x800000) + (inputValue & 0x7fffff)

    
    def is_ready(self):
        return GPIO.input(self.DOUT) == 0

    
    def set_gain(self, gain):
        if gain is 128:
            self.GAIN = 1
        elif gain is 64:
            self.GAIN = 3
        elif gain is 32:
            self.GAIN = 2

        GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, False)

        # Read out a set of raw bytes and throw it away.
        self.readRawBytes()

        
    def get_gain(self):
        if self.GAIN == 1:
            return 128
        if self.GAIN == 3:
            return 64
        if self.GAIN == 2:
            return 32

        # Shouldn't get here.
        return 0
        

    def readNextBit(self):
       # Clock HX711 Digital Serial Clock (PD_SCK).  DOUT will be
       # ready 1us after PD_SCK rising edge, so we sample after
       # lowering PD_SCL, when we know DOUT will be stable.
       GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, True)
       GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, False)
       value = GPIO.input(self.DOUT)

       # Convert Boolean to int and return it.
       return int(value)


    def readNextByte(self):
       byteValue = 0

       # Read bits and build the byte from top, or bottom, depending
       # on whether we are in MSB or LSB bit mode.
       for x in range(8):
          if self.bit_format == 'MSB':
             byteValue <<= 1
             byteValue |= self.readNextBit()
          else:
             byteValue >>= 1              
             byteValue |= self.readNextBit() * 0x80

       # Return the packed byte.
       return byteValue 
        

    def readRawBytes(self):
        # Wait for and get the Read Lock, incase another thread is already
        # driving the HX711 serial interface.
        self.readLock.acquire()

        # Wait until HX711 is ready for us to read a sample.
        while not self.is_ready():
           pass

        # Read three bytes of data from the HX711.
        firstByte  = self.readNextByte()
        secondByte = self.readNextByte()
        thirdByte  = self.readNextByte()

        # HX711 Channel and gain factor are set by number of bits read
        # after 24 data bits.
        for i in range(self.GAIN):
           # Clock a bit out of the HX711 and throw it away.
           self.readNextBit()

        # Release the Read Lock, now that we've finished driving the HX711
        # serial interface.
        self.readLock.release()           

        # Depending on how we're configured, return an orderd list of raw byte
        # values.
        if self.byte_format == 'LSB':
           return [thirdByte, secondByte, firstByte]
        else:
           return [firstByte, secondByte, thirdByte]


    def read_long(self):
        # Get a sample from the HX711 in the form of raw bytes.
        dataBytes = self.readRawBytes()


        if self.DEBUG_PRINTING:
            print(dataBytes,)
        
        # Join the raw bytes into a single 24bit 2s complement value.
        twosComplementValue = ((dataBytes[0] << 16) |
                               (dataBytes[1] << 8)  |
                               dataBytes[2])

        if self.DEBUG_PRINTING:
            print("Twos: 0x%06x" % twosComplementValue)
        
        # Convert from 24bit twos-complement to a signed value.
        signedIntValue = self.convertFromTwosComplement24bit(twosComplementValue)

        # Record the latest sample value we've read.
        self.lastVal = signedIntValue

        # Return the sample value we've read from the HX711.
        return int(signedIntValue)

    
    def read_average(self, times=3):
        # Make sure we've been asked to take a rational amount of samples.
        if times <= 0:
            raise ValueError("HX711()::read_average(): times must >= 1!!")

        # If we're only average across one value, just read it and return it.
        if times == 1:
            return self.read_long()

        # If we're averaging across a low amount of values, just take the
        # median.
        if times < 5:
            return self.read_median(times)

        # If we're taking a lot of samples, we'll collect them in a list, remove
        # the outliers, then take the mean of the remaining set.
        valueList = []

        for x in range(times):
            valueList += [self.read_long()]

        valueList.sort()

        # We'll be trimming 20% of outlier samples from top and bottom of collected set.
        trimAmount = int(len(valueList) * 0.2)

        # Trim the edge case values.
        valueList = valueList[trimAmount:-trimAmount]

        # Return the mean of remaining samples.
        return sum(valueList) / len(valueList)


    # A median-based read method, might help when getting random value spikes
    # for unknown or CPU-related reasons
    def read_median(self, times=3):
       if times <= 0:
          raise ValueError("HX711::read_median(): times must be greater than zero!")
      
       # If times == 1, just return a single reading.
       if times == 1:
          return self.read_long()

       valueList = []

       for x in range(times):
          valueList += [self.read_long()]

       valueList.sort()

       # If times is odd we can just take the centre value.
       if (times & 0x1) == 0x1:
          return valueList[len(valueList) // 2]
       else:
          # If times is even we have to take the arithmetic mean of
          # the two middle values.
          midpoint = len(valueList) / 2
          return sum(valueList[midpoint:midpoint+2]) / 2.0


    # Compatibility function, uses channel A version
    def get_value(self, times=3):
        return self.get_value_A(times)


    def get_value_A(self, times=3):
        return self.read_median(times) - self.get_offset_A()


    def get_value_B(self, times=3):
        # for channel B, we need to set_gain(32)
        g = self.get_gain()
        self.set_gain(32)
        value = self.read_median(times) - self.get_offset_B()
        self.set_gain(g)
        return value

    # Compatibility function, uses channel A version
    def get_weight(self, times=3):
        return self.get_weight_A(times)


    def get_weight_A(self, times=3):
        value = self.get_value_A(times)
        value = value / self.REFERENCE_UNIT
        return value

    def get_weight_B(self, times=3):
        value = self.get_value_B(times)
        value = value / self.REFERENCE_UNIT_B
        return value

    
    # Sets tare for channel A for compatibility purposes
    def tare(self, times=15):
        self.tare_A(times)
    
    
    def tare_A(self, times=15):
        # Backup REFERENCE_UNIT value
        backupReferenceUnit = self.get_reference_unit_A()
        self.set_reference_unit_A(1)
        
        value = self.read_average(times)

        if self.DEBUG_PRINTING:
            print("Tare A value:", value)
        
        self.set_offset_A(value)

        # Restore the reference unit, now that we've got our offset.
        self.set_reference_unit_A(backupReferenceUnit)

        return value


    def tare_B(self, times=15):
        # Backup REFERENCE_UNIT value
        backupReferenceUnit = self.get_reference_unit_B()
        self.set_reference_unit_B(1)

        # for channel B, we need to set_gain(32)
        backupGain = self.get_gain()
        self.set_gain(32)

        value = self.read_average(times)

        if self.DEBUG_PRINTING:
            print("Tare B value:", value)
        
        self.set_offset_B(value)

        # Restore gain/channel/reference unit settings.
        self.set_gain(backupGain)
        self.set_reference_unit_B(backupReferenceUnit)
       
        return value


    
    def set_reading_format(self, byte_format="LSB", bit_format="MSB"):
        if byte_format == "LSB":
            self.byte_format = byte_format
        elif byte_format == "MSB":
            self.byte_format = byte_format
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unrecognised byte_format: \"%s\"" % byte_format)

        if bit_format == "LSB":
            self.bit_format = bit_format
        elif bit_format == "MSB":
            self.bit_format = bit_format
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unrecognised bitformat: \"%s\"" % bit_format)

            


    # sets offset for channel A for compatibility reasons
    def set_offset(self, offset):
        self.set_offset_A(offset)

    def set_offset_A(self, offset):
        self.OFFSET = offset

    def set_offset_B(self, offset):
        self.OFFSET_B = offset

    def get_offset(self):
        return self.get_offset_A()

    def get_offset_A(self):
        return self.OFFSET

    def get_offset_B(self):
        return self.OFFSET_B


    
    def set_reference_unit(self, reference_unit):
        self.set_reference_unit_A(reference_unit)

        
    def set_reference_unit_A(self, reference_unit):
        # Make sure we aren't asked to use an invalid reference unit.
        if reference_unit == 0:
            raise ValueError("HX711::set_reference_unit_A() can't accept 0 as a reference unit!")
            return

        self.REFERENCE_UNIT = reference_unit

        
    def set_reference_unit_B(self, reference_unit):
        # Make sure we aren't asked to use an invalid reference unit.
        if reference_unit == 0:
            raise ValueError("HX711::set_reference_unit_A() can't accept 0 as a reference unit!")
            return

        self.REFERENCE_UNIT_B = reference_unit


    def get_reference_unit(self):
        return get_reference_unit_A()

        
    def get_reference_unit_A(self):
        return self.REFERENCE_UNIT

        
    def get_reference_unit_B(self):
        return self.REFERENCE_UNIT_B
        
        
    def power_down(self):
        # Wait for and get the Read Lock, incase another thread is already
        # driving the HX711 serial interface.
        self.readLock.acquire()

        # Cause a rising edge on HX711 Digital Serial Clock (PD_SCK).  We then
        # leave it held up and wait 100 us.  After 60us the HX711 should be
        # powered down.
        GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, False)
        GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, True)

        time.sleep(0.0001)

        # Release the Read Lock, now that we've finished driving the HX711
        # serial interface.
        self.readLock.release()           


    def power_up(self):
        # Wait for and get the Read Lock, incase another thread is already
        # driving the HX711 serial interface.
        self.readLock.acquire()

        # Lower the HX711 Digital Serial Clock (PD_SCK) line.
        GPIO.output(self.PD_SCK, False)

        # Wait 100 us for the HX711 to power back up.
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        # Release the Read Lock, now that we've finished driving the HX711
        # serial interface.
        self.readLock.release()

        # HX711 will now be defaulted to Channel A with gain of 128.  If this
        # isn't what client software has requested from us, take a sample and
        # throw it away, so that next sample from the HX711 will be from the
        # correct channel/gain.
        if self.get_gain() != 128:
            self.readRawBytes()


    def reset(self):
        self.power_down()
        self.power_up()


# EOF - hx711.py
```

[image]

Comment: add these three symbols ``` in a blank line before the code ... do the same in a blank line after the code ... make sure that it is not on the same line as any of the code

Comment: just a python reminder: ... indentation is used for defining code blocks  (other programming languages use braces or parentheses) ... indent by tabs is not the same as indent by spaces even if the code lines up ... you will get messages when executing improperly indented code

Comment: @jsotola thanks, adding the ``` in a blank like did it ugh...had them straight before and after the code.

Comment: The runtime error msg says your pin numbering is wrong: ***RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)***.So you need to set either Board mode or BCM mode, and make sure you hardware pin numbers match you set mode.

Comment: @Milliways, thx for replying. The main approach incl. the connections were taken from here https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/digital-raspberry-pi-scale-weight-sensor-hx711/

Comment: sorry seem not to be able to comment..ugh age is catching up..I have edited my post, hope it makes more sense

Comment: @tlfong01 the GPIO.setmode is done in HX711.py which is called in example.py and mode is set to BCM hence I use the GPIOs and not the pins but yeah I don't know why it's complaining about that

Comment: I read the code you are running: "HX711 tatobari/hx711py Python GitHub program hx711.py (Using threading, mutex)":
https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py/blob/master/hx711.py. and found that it has the following statement: "***GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)***". In other words the program set BMC mode. so you need to match the BCM pin numbers to your pins used. BTW, tatobari github's code is a bit advanced, using scary things like "threading" and "mutex", which are hard to debug. / to continue, ...

Comment: I would suggest to use a simple version like this: HX711 Python Library hx711 1.1.2.3 pip install hx711 - pypy.org
https://pypi.org/project/hx711/. For this simple library, you can start testing just one channel. And that you don't need to use any load cell for initial testing. Put away the load cell, Just test one channel with input connected ground, and to Vcc.

Comment: @Cem, Ah there is some confusion here. HX711 is using the Rpi GPIO pins directly (I mean not through I2C, SPI, or UART). So you connect HX711 to Rpi GPIO pins, which have two schemes of numbering, BCM and BOARD. In other words, any one pin might be numbered "x" in BCM scheme, but "y" in BOARD scheme.  This is a top 3 Rpi newbie error or sorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115519/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-cem).

Comment: Perhaps have a look at Arduino solutions.  To get this working on a Pi you would need to make an investment in understanding software and Python and I don't think it would be a reliable solution either (the HX711 has some timing requirements which make it difficult to have two working on the Pi at the same time).